# How to use the Jdom package?

Tags: java, xml, macos, jdom

I want to use the Jdom package to use .XML files for my application.
I have downloaded the Jdom's build 2.0.6.

But now, I don't know how to install it.
If someone can guide me..

(I'm on macOs)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you downloaded JDOM jar file, then simply include it to your java project in IDE. 
If you use IntelliJ IDEA, then follow these steps:

1. *File > Project Structure > Libraries > New Project Library > Java*
2. Find your jar file
3. Add it to your project

If you use Maven, then you can add this code to your `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jdom</groupId>
    <artifactId>jdom</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

You can view all available versions on [Maven Central](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jdom/jdom).

If you use Eclipse IDE, then follow these steps :

1. Right click on your project > Build Path > Configure Build Path > Add external JARs
2. Select your JAR
3. Apply and save